# How to import entries from Craft 2 to Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, entries, migration, export

So, I've been working on a Craft 3 upgrade, managed to set everything up, including configuring new plugins etc. Since I've started working on the upgrade process, some new entries have been published on the original site (running on Craft 2).

What's the best way to import only the blog entries from the latest database dump? I tried to replace the `craft_content` table in the database, but that doesn't seem to work well - I assume the table structure is different on Craft 3?

Is there maybe any plugin for doing such thing?

I also thought of getting the fresh DB dump from the live site, converting it to Craft 3 and then replacing the `craft_content` table, but I'm not convinced if that's the best way to do it.

Or maybe I should replace some other tables too? Couldn't find any DB description in Craft documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this would be to use something like https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me, where you could setup a feed of the data you want to export, map it to the proper fields in Craft 3, then import the data from a feed.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but how exactly do I export feed from Craft 2? I've tried already "Export" from Bob Olde Hampsink and "Out" from Ether Creative, but unfortunately Export doesn't work at all (getting some php error while trying to run it), and Out doesn't work with my entry type. I guess plugins for this task are not being supported anymore - what can I do now? Doing this manually would take too much time. Is there any way to export single database table with blog posts from the updated database and replace it?

Comment: @krzk Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I'm facing a similar task, where I've upgraded a Craft 2 site to Craft 3 and now need to grab all the content changes made to the old DB...